# Is "I'd like to introduce to you" still in use? Does it fit in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

With a great deal of pleasure, I'd like to introduce to you one of the most respected criminal prosecutors in the country, Ms. ABC.

Answer (score 1):

I find the formulation in use, and yes, it fits in your sentence.  It is a social formalism that has had all meaning drained from it, and in these situations it merely means "I am going to."  Note that no one listening to the introduction is prepared to believe that the host is really deriving any pleasure from the task or even finds it agreeable.  And no one is going to notice the slight redundancy in "with pleasure" and "I'd like."

The locution is often balanced with a contrary:

```
A: Would you like to go to lunch?
B: I'd like to, but I can't.  I have another appointment.
```

This leaves a possible literal interpretation of the introduction as "To avoid awkwardness, I'd like to introduce Ms ABC as one of the most respected criminal prosecutors in the country.  But, in truth, I can't do that because no one in the bar thinks she's anything but a low-life weasel."

For the sake of social propriety, everyone in the room will ignore this possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the Beatles are any index to the vernacular, then the answer would be "yes." Here's the lyrics to their song *Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band* as published online:

> That the singer's going to sing a song
>   And he wants you all to sing along
>   **So let me introduce to you**
>   The one and only Billy Shears
>   And Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band

Comment: To be fair, that song is just a couple of years shy of its half-century mark. I'll leave it to the OP to declare if that counts as "still in use"!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "May I introduce" instead... shorter, cleaner, not so awkward.